# How to sort a listBox in C#?

Tags: c#, listbox

I have typed numbers in a textbox and added them into a listBox. Now I need to order that listbox. This is my try:

```
int[] array = listBox1.Items.Cast<int>().ToArray<int>();
Array.Sort(array);
listBox1.Items.Clear();
foreach (int item in array)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(item);
}
```

It throws an 'System.InvalidCastException'. But I can't figure it out HOW to solve it.

Comment: why you are taking the same listbox items and add it to the same again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a lambda

```
var array = listBox1.Items.OfType<string>().Select(x => int.Parse(x))
                             .ToArray();
```

Comment: Visual doesn't recognize Items.Select

Comment: yep, not working 'ListBox.ObjectCollection doesn't have a definition for select'

Comment: Is it .OfType<string>() ? ...then Parse(x)

Comment: I don't know how to check the type of the items, but I guess that even they are strings I have to order the items as numbers. This is because if I order them as strings  5, 2, 10 would be order as 10, 2, 5.

Comment: The ordering can remain the same as you did if it works. I am parsing from string to int indeed. I was helping you with the array first where you have an error. Try again after last update... :-)

Comment: Sorry to say it, but it doesn't order the ListBox

Comment: It doesn't order the ListBox

Comment: Is array sorted after the Sort? Have you debugged the clear and the following add... ? ... Is there some other code (not shown here) that is interfering?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. As I don't understand LINQ nor lambda I had a hard time understanding the code so I just copy and pasted it. Now I made the corrections and it sorts correctly, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is as simple as

```
listBox1.Sorted = true;
```

**UPDATE**

```
var array = new object[listBox1.Items.Count];
listBox1.Items.CopyTo(array, 0);
listBox1.Items.Clear();
var sortedArray = array.Select(n => (object)Convert.ToInt32(n)).OrderBy(n => n).ToArray();
listBox1.Items.AddRange(sortedArray);
```

Comment: They are numbers, so if i do that 10, 5, 9 is ordered 10, 5, 9 . It understands the 10 as a 1.

Comment: Doesn't order the listBox1 : (

Comment: @user3646717 see the edit :) The problem was that the items you are adding to the list box are not integers, but strings

Comment: @user3646717 well, thanks :). please change the answer checkmark and vote up so the others can use it in the future

Answer (score 0):

First, I want to say that it is not a good idea to store data inside a control. Always put your data inside types that can handle them like a List, Dictionary, etc. and then bind that to your listbox object. I guess you are working on windows forms. Then add a property to your form and put all your data in it.

something like this

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
List<string> _items = new List<string>(); // <-- Add this

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    _items.Add("One"); // <-- Add these
    _items.Add("Two");
    _items.Add("Three");

    listBox1.DataSource = _items;
}
public void add()
{
 _items.Add("four");
 _items.Sort();
}
}
```

Comment: If I do that, everytime I try to add a number from the TextBox into the ListBox, I have to clear the whole ListBox, then refill it with all the data from the List, not considering that I have to convert it to an int in order to properly sort it.

Comment: Ok, but that is the way to do it. You have to have your data source and your data views separated.

Comment: Yeap, after trying with all other methods I did it like you said and resulted the best method. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

ListBox items can cast to string. So, You must cast it to string[], then convert to int[], then sort it and finally add sorted data to ListBox.

```
        string[] strArray = listBox1.Items.Cast<string>().ToArray();
        int[] intArray = strArray.Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToArray();
        Array.Sort(intArray);
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        foreach (int item in intArray)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(item);
        }
```

I hope this will be useful.